# Supplying relative path in qt .pro (project) file works for one variable, not for the other

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have the following lines in my .pro file and it works fine.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "Xerces/include"

LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/Xerces/lib/" -lxerces-c_3
```

But I noticed I *have to* use the _PRO_FILE_PWD variable for LIBS variable otherwise it wouldn't find the library if I just use the relative path like in  INCLUDEPATH variable.

Why does relative path work for INCLUDEPATH but not for LIBS ?